# Angular Directive throws $digest already in progress when trying to call controller method

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

Here is my plunker - http://plnkr.co/edit/VYH5QbO99ZbMkvc2D4Fe?p=preview

- I want to keep the knowledge of controller method outside of directive so used Directive Attribute and pass controller method inside
- Now it is failing that `$digest already in progress` (see `console.log`)

**UPDATE**
The body of `HTML` in firebug looks like

```
<body data-ng-controller="SummaryController" class="ng-scope">
    <h1>Hello Directive!</h1>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    <div summary="loadPie1()">
     <div>
      <div id="pie1">I am pie 1</div>
      <div id="pie2">I am pie 2</div>
     </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Please help

Comment: are you always passing a function that is defined in the scope?

Comment: yes I am doing that, and you can see that in plunker code I have shared

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `scope.$apply` is not needed there. The link function is called and the template is built with the scope, so you are trying to apply scope changes for template that is being built

http://jimhoskins.com/2012/12/17/angularjs-and-apply.html

One way to solve it is:

```
app.directive('summary', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    scope : {
       summary : '='
    },
    templateUrl: 'summary.html',
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs){
      console.log('directive: call to load pie1');
      scope.summary();
    }
  }
});

app.controller('SummaryController', function($scope){
  console.log('controller glued');
  $scope.loadPie1 = function() {
        console.log('controller: will load pie1');
  };
});


<div summary="loadPie1"></div>
```

You can pass the actual function closure, instead of a string

Comment: so how can I call my method `loadPie1()`. I used `scope.$apply()` by learning from http://www.egghead.io/video/LJmZaxuxlRc

Comment: This approach works, but I am not sure why approach in http://www.egghead.io/video/LJmZaxuxlRc is not working for me? the only difference is that in this video it binds mouse events and then call `scope.$apply(attrs.enter)`

Comment: because when you bind it, the actual event happens later. When you run scope.$apply() it executes the digest process which has not finished running during the previous compile (that initiates the directive)

Comment: @daydreamer: I was getting that error too. I fixed it by using $timeout to delay the $apply call since I wasn't doing the action later (e.g., after mouse event) as @galchen mentions. So I did this: 
`app.directive('summary', ['$timeout', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            $timeout(function () { scope.$apply(attrs.summary); }, 0);
        },
 templateUrl: 'summary.html'
    };
}]);`